# apache server A attempts conn to mysql server B. times out. what am i missing?

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, mysql

I have an apache web server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)) running 
PHP 5.3.2. I am trying to make a connection with php to a new Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit server running mysql server. Heres a run down of the settings in place.

- mysql server version 5.1
- There are no firewall rules restricting connections between these two machines. neither in our hardware firewall or in iptables.
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf has the bind-address set to the machine's ip.
- skip-networking is commented out, ie disabled.
- mysql is running and on the standard port 3306

the following is my php connection script:

```
<?php

$nl = "<br>";

$host="555.555.55.55";
$user="some_user";
$pass="some_pass";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$conn){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() . $nl);
}
else {
        echo "connected!";
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

attempting to execute the php script in a browser hosted on the apache server only yields: "Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '555.555.55.55' (4)"

any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Test 1 has got to be:

```
apachebox% telnet mysqlbox 3306
```

if that doesn't connect, you have a problem which must be sorted before anything else will work.

Comment: +1 for this answer, the first test is to check for connectivity!

Comment: If this works, you should also try 'mysql -u some_user -h 555.555.55.55 -p' before trying to connect from PHP

Comment: ah, sorry, this follow up answer was posted on askubuntu.com. mysql -u root -p -h <ubuntu-server-ip> from redhat yields: "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '555.555.55.55' (110)"

Comment: Trying 555.555.55.55...
telnet: connect to address 555.555.55.55: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

If it's a timeout, install tshark. (Your package manager should have a current version)

On the client and server: (add `-i <adaptor>` if it's not `eth0` that's being used)

```
tshark port 3306
```

Try the connection again and watch both sessions to see where the packets are being dropped. This will narrow down where to look, to start with.

Comment: `tcpdump port 3306` will also do the job on RHEL and derived OS's

Answer (score 0):

SELinux? Maybe it is enabled and not configured.

Can you connect to your Mysql server from another client within LAN?

Comment: If this is the case check /var/log/audit/audit.log for denied messages, and `getenforce` to check if SELinux is running.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the ip of the machine to a different ip range within our institution. from a private range to a public ip. it now connects. We're now investigating this private range. Thanks for everyones help!